# how to add a object to an object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am unable to add a object to object.
i am creating a object with two 2 properties
i want to assign this object to another object

```
$scope.urlMappings = {};
$scope.Mapping = function() {
            
            var newUrlMappingField = {};
            newUrlMappingField.Url1 = '';
            newUrlMappingField.Url2 = '';

            $scope.urlMappings.push(newUrlMappingField); 
and wat key would i need to use to call ng-repeat in html file ? i m using mapping in urlMappings
```

I am unable to add a object to object.
i am creating a object with two 2 properties
i want to assign this object to another object
and wat key would i need to use to call ng-repeat in html file ? i m using mapping in urlMappings

Comment: Could you write down your question in a more precise form? Especially explaining with more details the part about ng-repeat. Anyway it's not correct to call push on a JS object to add another object into it. You should assign the inner object as a new property of the outer object like: `outerObj.myProp = innerObj;`

Answer (score 0):

`push()` method is used to add items to an `array`, not an `object`.

To add items to an object you can use the bracket notation to set the property of the object and assign the new object to it.

```
  $scope.urlMappings = {};
  $scope.Mapping = function() {
    var newUrlMappingField = {};
    newUrlMappingField.Url1 = '';
    newUrlMappingField.Url2 = '';
    $scope.urlMappings["mapping"] = newUrlMappingField;
  }
```

For the second question, as far as i understand

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in urlMappings">
   <div>{{key}}: {{value.Url1}} {{value.Url2}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: kandeal
we have two input tags for url1 and url2 respectively with one add button
onclick of add button the input tags should repeat
so wat should i use for ng-repeat ??